# sqlstate[23000]: integrity constraint violation: 1062 duplicate entry '1827' for key 'primary'

Tags: php, mysql, magento, duplicates, mysql-error-1062

My webhost is siteground and they asked me to reduce my SQL size as it has exceeded the limit. I done so, following their instructions and now my website is broken. I emptied the visitors log, and url logs in phpMyAdmin as they were taking up most of the space and now my website is not working and siteground want me to pay them to restore my website back to a working date even though it is their instructions on how to empty the files that broke my site for a second time. Below is the error I am getting. I have not upgraded my site since July 2014 with the new files that have come out since, and there has been quite a few from the template provider, and have not upgraded my magento, so I am still using 1.9.0.

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1827' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: you gotta reset the auto_increment value, after you remove all those extra lines. the problem is that It's trying to insert another record with the same ID

Comment: 'ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1' and set 1 to the highest primary key value

Comment: @iam-decoder Where would I find the file to do this please? I am new at this and learning along the way. I went into lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php and changed the value to 1 and it still done nothing  $position           = count($this->_columns);
        $default            = false;
        $nullable           = true;
        $length             = null;
        $scale              = null;
        $precision          = null;
        $unsigned           = false;
        $primary            = false;
        $primaryPosition    = 1;
        $identity           = false;

Comment: @Belinda22 There's no file, its a query to run in your SQL database, I'm assuming you're using MySQL. Run `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = xxx` where xxx is the LAST `'PRIMARY'` in the table

Comment: @Crecket Where would I find the file to do this please? I am new at this and learning along the way. I went into lib/Varien/Db/Ddl/Table.php and changed the value to 1 and it still done nothing $position = count($this->_columns); $default = false; $nullable = true; $length = null; $scale = null; $precision = null; $unsigned = false; $primary = false; $primaryPosition = 1; $identity = false; –

Comment: @Belinda22 its not a file you have to change, go into phpmayadmin and click the SQL tab. Just enter it in there. Or if you can run a sql statement right now instead off for example SELECT you enter the command.

Answer (score 0):

this error occurs when database user has a access problem.
if you give full access (full permission) to db user then your problem is solve.